# What lightsaber form does Leia use?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Although I haven't read many novels which feature Leia dueling I have yet to find one that references her [lightsaber style](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_combat).

Is there reference to any media that states her style?

Comment: Might help narrow the search if there were any specific references where she does duel.  Can't think of one offhand.

Comment: Does Han Solo count?

Comment: She used the 'bludgeon them with the dangerous end' style.  In all honesty, she's not well-trained enough in lightsaber combat to have a style.  She knows the basic techniques, I'm sure, but she would probably lose to one of the Younglings in Episode II, were they to spar.

Comment: @joshbirk In EU content Doesn't she fight with the Palpatine clone? Wikipedia seems to think so. Also It suggests she faught a "Voxyn master slayer" in the Vong wars

Comment: @JamesKhoury - that's what I'm asking.  If there was a reference point to her actually using a lightsaber, someone might have a chance at guessing the form.  But her using the Force itself is rare - a lightsaber even rarer.  And by reference point, I'm suggesting the author should research a quote of some kind.

Comment: @joshbirk I think guessing a lightsaber form is a rather hard thing to do. Is it a surprise to look for expert knowledge here?

Comment: @JamesKhoury - Looking for expert knowledge here is not odd.  Asking for someone to guess a lightsaber form without even describing so much as an actual event when she used said lightsaber is probably expecting a bit much.  The way the question reads right now it is hard to determine she ever really seriously used one.  So my guess is her form is "holding a lightsaber".

Comment: Leia using a lightsaber is not canon anyway.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple occasions where Leia uses a lightsaber in combat, notably against her brother (in training) in *Ambush at Corellia* and against Alema Rar on two separate occasions during *The Dark Nest Trilogy*.

There has never been any mention of which lightsaber style Leia uses, possibly because the idea of lightsaber "combat styles" is a relatively new invention from the Clone Wars era of the *EU*, possibly because they are a stupid idea in their own right, and possibly because Leia's training is haphazard and prolonged, keeping her from ever developing an established style.

Comment: Stupid idea? Can you explain that one?

Comment: If all Jedi train together, why would they have separate lightsaber styles? You'll notice that mixed martial artists who train together don't continue to 'switch' between styles, as both Obi-Wan and Anakin do in at least one *EU* story; *The Revenge of the Sith* novelisation, which is actually surprisingly good). I can understand Jedi, Sith, Nightsisters, etc., all having different styles, but the idea that a single monastic order would train in different fighting styles is unsupported by real world examples.

Comment: Not all Jedi trained together. Different Masters might teach different forms. I understand it might be a stretch of the imagination but I couldn't dismiss it as 'stupid'.

Comment: I come from a martial arts background. Believe me, given the establishment of the Jedi Order as a relatively centralised institution with a strong focus on tradition, it is stupid. Ironically, if the *EU*'s focus on the Jedi Order as decentralised had been kept up by Lucas in the prequel trilogy, then I would have no issue with separate schools of Jedi lightsaber combat.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - How many styles exist merely within Kung-Fu?

Comment: A better question would be how many of those styles are taught within the same school of Kung-Fu? All institutions, even the cross-training institutions that have sprung up with the popularity of MMA, teach a single style, or at most an amalgam of several styles. Some gyms teach multiple styles, but only because they have different instructors with different backgrounds teaching on different days. The Jedi Order is far more akin to a single monastic order than a gymnasium, so why would they teach multiple lightsaber disciplines?

Comment: Different instructors with different backgrounds on different days? Different masters with different cultures on different planets. The jedi order wasnt some all knowing religon. They disagreed with each other kn things, so why not on lightsaber styles.

Comment: Different orders do not have different styles. The Jedi Order is portrayed as a monastic order on the style of the Shaolin in our own time. Different styles would imply schisms within the order. Wile we know that has happened in the past, the Jedi Order at the time of the prequel films is shown to be united. As such, it makes no sense for the Order to teach different styles as part of its own training program. When the best argument you can come up with is "why not," perhaps you shouldn't be attempting to argue the point with a guy who used to earn a living performing martial arts.

Comment: The wikipedia page for [Shaolin Kung fu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaolin_Kung_Fu#List_of_styles_currently_taught_at_the_temple) lists about 15 styles currently taught at the Shaolin Temple. I don't believe there are schisms within their order either. If the Shaolin can live with teaching 15 distinct styles, why can't the Jedi do the same with less than 10?

Comment: Shaoling Kung Fu is a collection of martial arts that claim affinity with the temple. This is absolutely no different from the gym around the corner from my house teaching five different martial arts. The Shaolin temple is not what it once was, but is largely a tourist attraction these days. Case in point: there were "Shaolin monks" in my home town last year, performing acrobatics that would not have been out of place in a circus. That is a far cry from practicing martial arts as a form of spiritual enlightenment, or even for protection. You're not claiming the Jedi were a tourist attraction?

Comment: Well, it seems to me they were often paraded before dignitaries, but that's beside the point. Different Jedi Masters will have different personalities and will face different foes that use different weapons and tactics. It seems very likely to me that that some masters will thus specialize in different areas of lightsaber combat. Those Jedi will become references for these specific kinds of missions where their skills are most useful. Their padawans take on their training and a few generations down the line, complete styles have sprung up. Sounds a lot like developping martial arts to me...

Comment: Said martial arts split into different schools. What you have described is Karate or Kung Fu as a whole, not individual institutions. The Jedi Order is very much a different institution, and while different Masters might focus on different aspects of lightsaber discipline - different senseis focus on different aspects of even basic martial arts today - that is nowhere near enough differentiation to establish a different style.

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember any specific mentions of her light saber form.

In the rare case that the book covers got it right:
The [Dark nest trilogy: The unseen Queen](http://www.theforce.net/books/reviews/r_dn2-unseenqueen.asp) cover and the [Legacy of the Force: Exile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exile_%28Star_Wars_novel%29) cover both have her holding a saber.

Also on wikia there is a [Leia fighting Vader picture](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_on_Mimban)

This is a total guess: **Form I: Shii-cho**
Reasoning: This was the form taught to younglings and one would assume she might be taught it first. This image depicting a Shii-cho blaster deflect. 
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Shii-ChoBlastDeflect.png

Comment: Why would Luke, who had a limited training doctrine, even have a concept of different lightsaber styles, let alone the ability to teach multiple styles to his students?

Comment: Leia was not taught that much by Luke. She had another master complete her training.

Comment: I am aware that Leia completed her training under Saba Sebatyne. That wasn't until several decades after the Battle of Endor. In the meantime, Luke taught her.

Answer (score 0):

Luke would have the concept of styles from the old Jedi holocrons. I'm sure there's plenty of them from the Old Republic order. As for her training she did complete it. However, it's actually really rare she uses her lightsaber, as I'm sure her kids have seen more combat action than she has.

Comment: There's a lot of "I'm sure" in this answer but no citations. Can you cite any sources?